# How to configure logging for all Rust integration tests at once?

Tags: rust

I have sources in `src/` directory and tests together with them in the same files. Then, in `src/lib.rs` I have this:

```
#[cfg(test)]
use simple_logger::SimpleLogger;
#[cfg(test)]
use log::LevelFilter;
#[cfg(test)]
#[ctor::ctor]
fn init() {
    SimpleLogger::new()
        .with_level(LevelFilter::Trace)
        .init()
        .unwrap();
}
```

This turns logging on for all *unit* tests.

Then, I have integration tests in `tests/` directory. If I put the same code into `tests/lib.rs`, it makes no effect. Where can I put it so that logging is configured by integration tests the same way as it's done for unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this is not working is that integration tests are separate crates which depend on the lib crate - but without the `#[cfg(test)]` enabled. I'm not sure there even is a `cfg` flag you could use to know that the lib crate is being compiled for integration testing, but it would not be clean to do such a thing anyway. Instead, you could adopt the method described in [Rust By Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/testing/integration_testing.html): put the code you posted into a `tests/common/mod.rs` and add `mod common;` to all your integration tests. If that is still too much work per test, you could have your integration tests under a separate `Cargo.toml` of the same workspace, and have that `Cargo.toml` have a library that compiles the code you posted unconditionally (and never publish that to `crates.io`).

Comment: I added `tests/common/mod.rs`